# Method to return a collection - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, collections, iteration

Say, I have a method called `posted_listings`, which is supposed to run an ActiveRecord query and return a collection of `User.listings` where `posted: true`, with **`posted?` being a `Listing` class method**. So far I have been doing:

```
class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  def posted_listings
    posted_listings = []
    listings.each { |listing| posted_listings << listing if listing.posted? }
    posted_listing
  end
end
```

but each time this query runs I start feeling really bad about my skills (or lack of thereof). What is the most efficient way to return a collection of posted listings?

#### Edit:

`posted?` is not an attribute, its a class method:

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
 def posted?
    true if quantity >= 1 && has_sellers? 
  end
end 

def has_sellers?
  sellers.count >=1 #association to Seller
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend adding a scope to your `Listing` model like this:

```
scope :posted, -> { where(posted: true) }
```

Then you can get all posted listings like this:

```
@user.listings.posted
```

You can learn more about scopes [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) if you are interested.

**UPDATE**

Try this scope instead:

```
def self.posted
  joins(:sellers)
    .where('posted = ? AND quantity > ?', true, 0)
    .group('listings.id')
    .having('COUNT(sellers.id) > ?', 0)
end
```

Comment: my problem is that `posted?` is a class method, not an attribute.

Comment: Could you list the full source of your `posted?` method? It still might be possible to use a scope, but I need to see that code first.

Comment: yep! ended up using raw SQL in `.where`.

Comment: I'm glad you got it working! And just a note about your original `posted_listings` method, it could be simplified down to `listings.select(&:posted?)`. Ruby has a lot of neat methods that allow you to make simplifications like this, so I thought you might be interested. I would recommend looking over the documentation for some of the core classes like [`String`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html), [`Array`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Array.html), and[`Hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Hash.html)  to get a sense of them. Doing this has helped me immensely with learning ruby!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not so clear for me.

You may try:

`User.listings.where(posted: true)`

to get all users' posted Listings.

Or, saying `@user`is an User instance:

`@user.listings.where(posted: true)`

to get posted Listings from an specific user.